# pandas DataFrame sum

Tags: pandas, dataframe, sum

Suppose I have a dataframe with numeric columns, A, B, C, D. I use pandas dataframe sum to summarize these columns. It returns a series like this
A             9237
B       965
C           5109
D             305
dtype: int64

I tried to separate it to two dataframe columns: Category, Counts. Haven't fount a solution yet. any ideas

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df2 = df.sum().to_frame().reset_index()

df2.rename(columns={'index' : 'Category', 0: 'Counts'})
```

Comment: @RobertZhou ur welcome, if it helps can u plz upvote the answer and check it as correct?